# Combine SQL Queries in Same Table

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I am trying to combine the following queries:

```
SELECT country_name, 
       avg(value) as Entrance_Age 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.world_bank_intl_education.international_education` 
WHERE indicator_code = 'UIS.THAGE.0' 
GROUP BY country_name
ORDER BY avg(value) DESC LIMIT 10

SELECT avg(value) as Illiterate
FROM `bigquery-public-data.world_bank_intl_education.international_education`
WHERE indicator_code = 'UIS.ILLPOP.AG25T64'
GROUP BY country_name
ORDER BY avg(value) DESC LIMIT 10
```

The output from the first query is:[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsxx7.png

The goal is to get another column named "Illiterate" next to Entrance_Age. I am trying to show the illiteracy rate for each of these 10 countries next to the Entrance Age column. All the data is from the same table. The values are linked to the indicator_code which is a statistics based on the indicator code.

I've tried multiple joins but can't seem to get one that works.

If there is anything I am missing from my question, please let me know.

Comment: hi Aly, don't explain your goal , explain what you want to output. do you want query show you both result Continuous? or maybe you want join it and orderby your specified condition

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT country_name, 
       avg(case when indicator_code = 'UIS.THAGE.0' then value end) as Entrance_Age,
       avg(case when indicator_code = 'UIS.ILLPOP.AG25T64' then value end) as illiterate 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.world_bank_intl_education.international_education` 
GROUP BY country_name
ORDER BY Entrance_Age DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thank you, Gordon!!